# Returning to Thread method after calling differnet method

Tags: python, multithreading, object

I'm not sure the best way to ask this (hence the crappy title).  In the `run()` method of a `threading.Thread` subclass I have an inf loop that needs to be returned too after different methods are run.  How is this accomplished?  Here is what I have so far (do i need `RLock()`s around the `plist` object within the same `Thread` instance?)

```
class pMonitor(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.plist = []

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for p in self.plist:
                if not p.isRunning():
                    p.run()
            time.sleep(1)

    def addproc(self, cmdline):
        self.plist.append(Proc(cmdline))
```

When calling `addproc`, how do I return to the loop inside `run()`? (or how should this be written to the same effect?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Queue.Queue`](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue):

```
def runproc(queue):
    plist = []
    while True:
        try: cmdline = queue.get_nowait()
        except Empty: pass
        else: plist.append(Proc(cmdline))

        for p in plist:
            if not p.isRunning():
               p.run()
        time.sleep(1)

queue = Queue()            
t = Thread(target=runproc, args=(queue,))
t.daemon = True
t.start()

queue.put(cmdline)
# ...
```

You need to add logic that removes processes from `plist`.